# phyloseq: Error in input$map_loaded : $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Tags: r, phyloseq

I am trying to make an NDMS plot with the `plot_ordinate` function in `phyloseq` and I keep getting this error. It worked for me previously. This is my code.

```r
dist <- phyloseq::distance(rf.indpig.decomp, method="bray")
ordination <- ordinate(rf.indpig.decomp, method="NDMS", 
                       distance=dist)
plot_ordination(rf.indpig.decomp, ordination,
    color="decomp.stage",shape="location")
```

> Error in input$map_loaded : $ operator not defined for this S4 class;

I get this feedback after the `plot_ordination`

Comment: could we please have a [mcve]? You haven't shown us anything about where `rf.indpig.decomp` comes from ...

Comment: rf.indpig.decomp is just a phyloseq object created using the phyloseq package. all other functions for phyloseq have worked for me